# .submit don't work when I use ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I build a website ,
the user need to sign up their information and a "special key"
if they didn't input the key , they will be normal user
if they use right key , they will be super user
but if key is wrong they will not pass until they use the right

the key used ajax to ckeck in controller
and return json {status:"ok"} or  {status:"error"}

here's my code

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){
    if(keystring.length > 0){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check",
        data: { key:keystring  },
        dataType:'json',
        async:false,
        success: function( datajson ) {
            if(datajson.status == "wrong"){
                alert("wrong, please input the right key");
            }else{
                $('#confirm').submit();
            }
        }
        });
     }else{
          $('#confirm').submit();
     }
});
```

the problem is
if I input right key or no key
$('#confirm').submit();  won't execute ！！

why?

submit will execute when not using ajax

Thanks for Help
here's my controller

```
def check
    @key = KeyChain.find_by({ code: params["key"]})
    if @user_info.present?
        datajson = { status:"ok" }
    else
        datajson = { status:"wrong"}
    end
    respond_to do |format|
     format.json {
        render :json => datajson.to_json 
     }
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you please show your form

Comment: need to see your html form

Comment: where have you initialized keystring?

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `keystring`? Is it defined, is it string, does it exist inside the closure? Try to show value of `keystring` with `alert` to see if it is OK.

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){
alert(keystring);
if(keystring.length > 0){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check",
    data: { key:keystring  },
    dataType:'json',
    async:false,
    success: function( datajson ) {
        if(datajson.status == "wrong"){
            alert("wrong, please input the right key");
        }else{
            $('#confirm').submit();
        }
    }
    });
 }else{
      $('#confirm').submit();
 }
});
```